# How to add effect to only the next div using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

When I click a button in the first div the effect implied on both the div.
How can I make the effect onclick of button be emplied only to the elements in the same div as the buttons?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button#first_button").click(function(){
  $("div#first_code").slideDown();
  $("div#second_code").slideUp();
 });
 
  $("button#second_button").click(function(){
  $("div#first_code").slideUp();
  $("div#second_code").slideDown();
 });
});
```

```html
<html><head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example">
 <div id="buttons">
  <button id="first_button">First</button>
  <button id="second_button">Second</button>
 </div>
 <div id="first_code">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="second_code" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Heading 2</h1>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="example">
 <div id="buttons">
  <button id="first_button">First</button>
  <button id="second_button">Second</button>
 </div>
 <div id="first_code">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="second_code" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Heading 2</h1>
 </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Use DOM navigation relative to `$(this)`

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't use the same ID in each DIV. Use classes for repeated elements.

Answer (score 1):

ID of the element should be unique across the HTML. You can use the below code to get the desired output.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".first_button").click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.example').find(".first_code").slideDown();
        $(this).parents('.example').find(".second_code").slideUp();
    });

    $(".second_button").click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.example').find(".first_code").slideUp();
        $(this).parents('.example').find(".second_code").slideDown();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="first_button">First</button>
        <button class="second_button">Second</button>
    </div>
    <div class="first_code">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="second_code" style="display: none;">
        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="example">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="first_button">First</button>
        <button class="second_button">Second</button>
    </div>
    <div class="first_code">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="second_code" style="display: none;">
        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```